# pygame.sprite.spritecollide only deleting enemy

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.8

I am making a spaceship game where you control a spaceship and fire bullets at the enemies. I am now trying to make both the player and the enemy spaceship disappear when both the player and the enemy collide. But when I try to use pygame.sprite.spritecollide, only the enemy disappears. Why is this? Is this because spritecollide only removes the sprites from its groups? (I set dokill to True)

This is my current code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint
from tools import *

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))


class Spaceship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, s, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("spaceship.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (175, 175))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, s, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.screen = s
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self):
        self.y -= 5
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        if self.y < 0:
            self.kill()


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, s, x, y, t):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.type = t
        self.screen, self.x, self.y = s, x, y
        self.image = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (235, 215))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        self.score_given = get_enemy_given_score()[self.type]

    def update(self):
        if self.y < 0:
            self.kill()
        self.y += 3
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)


spaceship = Spaceship(screen, 400, 400)

bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

enemy_interval = 5000  # It's in milliseconds
enemy_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(enemy_event, enemy_interval)

score = 0

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)
textsurface = font.render("Score: {:,}".format(score), True, (0, 0, 0))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet = Bullet(screen, spaceship.x, spaceship.y - 20)
            bullets.add(bullet)

        if event.type == enemy_event:
            enemy = Enemy(screen, randint(-150, 750), 0, "normal")
            enemies.add(enemy)

    bullets.update()

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    amount = 5

    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        spaceship.x -= amount
    elif key[pygame.K_d]:
        spaceship.x += amount
    elif key[pygame.K_w]:
        spaceship.y -= amount
    elif key[pygame.K_s]:
        spaceship.y += amount

    spaceship.update()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    screen.blit(spaceship.image, spaceship.rect)

    bullets.draw(screen)
    enemies.draw(screen)

    for i in enemies:
        i.update()
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(i, bullets, True):
            score += i.score_given
            i.kill()

    if score >= 99999:
        score = 99999

    textsurface = font.render("Score: {:,}".format(score), True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(textsurface, (590, 0))

    pygame.sprite.spritecollide(spaceship, enemies, dokill=True)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Just what I thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spaceship` cannot "disappear", because you have just 1 instance of the `Spaceship` class and you cannot remove it from a *Groups* (`kill`). If you don't want to see the spaceship anymore, just don't draw it:

```py
spaceship_collided = False

running = True
while running:
    # [...]

    if not spaceship_collided:
        screen.blit(spaceship.image, spaceship.rect)

    # [...]

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(spaceship, enemies, dokill=True):
        spaceship_collided = True

    # [...]
```

---

A different solution would be to use [`pygame.sprite.GroupSingle`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.GroupSingle):

```py
spaceship_group = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle(Spaceship(screen, 400, 400))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            
            if len(spaceship_group) > 0:
                spaceship = spaceship_group.sprites()[0]
                bullet = Bullet(screen, spaceship.x, spaceship.y - 20)
                bullets.add(bullet)

    # [...]

    spaceship_group.draw(screen)

    # [...]

    spaceship_group.update()

    # [...]
    
    pygame.sprite.groupcollide(spaceship_group, enemies, True, True)

    # [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the support!